# How data receive from server to variable in jQuery widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have to full rebuild Classic ASP.NET sites with interesting frontend. This site has very special frontend with a lot of various $.widget.

In HTML I have only one simple tag, for example

```
       <div id="pnProcuringEntity" class='col-12 p-0' />
```

In this page working widgets like similar

```
$.widget("Tender_Organization", {
    options: {
        anItem: "",
        id: "",
        OrganisationEditable: false,
        ReadOnly: true,
        OrganisationTitle: "",
        name_prefix: "",
        required: undefined
    },
    _create: function () {
        this.options.id = id_w_feature++;
        this._render();
   },
   _render: function () {
        var aWD = document.createElement("div");
        aWD.setAttribute("class", "row");
        var el = this.options;
        var PrefixId = "_" + el.id;
        var anItem = el.anItem;
        var name_prefix = el.name_prefix;

        controls =  "<div class='col-md-6'> " + .... + "</div>"
 ---> (1)
        
       $(aWD).append(controls);
        translate(aWD);
        this.element.html("");
        this.element.html(aWD);

 ---> (2)

        if (anItem.contactPoint != undefined) {
            if (anItem.contactPoint.name.uk_UA != undefined)
                anItem.PE_name = anItem.contactPoint.name.uk_UA;
            else
                anItem.PE_name = anItem.contactPoint.name;
        ....
     }

    Save: function () {...}
})
```

In the point (1) options property is empty. I see how new generated HTML adding to DOM. But in point (2) unexpectedly variable anItem has value and form can be fill data. I don't see any AJAX request to server. Alternatively I expect in form string like this (to receive static data from server)

```
var JsVariable = <% server Variable %>
```

but not found. JS scripts of that site is huge, more than 130 thousands of strings. In what way anItem value can receive data from server?

In the screen below I'm in break in point (2). New HTML added to DOM, and data unexpectedly appears in variables OPTIONS, but still not fill to form.

I'm sorry for my question, but I'm faced first time with similar frontend fully created by jQuery Widget. And this frontend is huge, obviously I'm not understanding how jQuery widget is working.

[image]

Comment: There seems to be a lot of missing items. For example, where is `id_w_feature` defined? What does `translate()` do? Where is it defined?

Comment: @Twisty. This is multi languages site, Translate is no more than changing Ukrainian-English literals from stored array. Variable id_w_feature mention only two times. (1) definition var id_w_feature = 0; and second time in _create: method.

Comment: Not sure how else to help at this time as I can not replicate the issue as this is not a Minimal, Reproducible Example. I see where `anItem` is created, and it is appears to be populated with `""`. Then it's translated, and items are added to the page, after that I am unsure where things go at that point.

Comment: Thank you. I still don't understand how value appear in variable anItem.